# Suppress initial inline citations biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm trying to suppress initials within inline citations. I'm using biblatex. I've searched through other posts, and found that setting `uniquename=false` and `uniquelist=false` has worked for other people. However, setting these options is not working for me. How can I get my citations to appear as follows:

'some text (Anderson 1999) and more text (Armenta *et al.* 2008)'.

My bib file is as follows:

```
@ARTICLE{AnderssonS1999,
  author = {{Andersson, S.}},
  title = {Morphology of UV reflectance in a whistling-thrush: implications
    for the study of structural colour signalling in birds},
  journal = {Journal of Avian Biology},
  year = {1999},
  volume = {30:},
  pages = {193-204}
}

@ARTICLE{armenta2008,
  author = {{Armenta, J.K., Dunn, P.O. \& Whittingham, L.A.}},
  title = {{Effects of specimen age on plumage color}},
  journal = {The Auk},
  year = {2008},
  volume = {125:},
  pages = {803--808},
  file = {:Users/rossahmed/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Armenta, Dunn, Whittin\textit{g\textit{}}ham - 2008 - Effects of specimen age on plumage color.pdf:pdf},
  publisher = {BioOne},
  url = {http://www.bioone.org/doi/abs/10.1525/auk.2008.07006}
}
```

My .tex file is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[firstinits=true,style=authoryear-comp,natbib=true,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,uniquename=false,uniquelist=false,sorting=none]{biblatex}



\addbibresource{test.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\iSDot}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace} % remove comma inline citations


\makeatletter
\ifcsundef{abx@macro@\detokenize{date+extrayear}}{%
  }{%
  \renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{year}{%
      }{%
      \addperiod\space
      \printtext{\printdateextra}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother


\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}
\DeclareNameFormat[article,periodical,book,electronic]{author}{\mkbibbold{#1}}


\begin{document}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{date}
\maketitle

some text \parencite{AnderssonS1999} and more text \parencite{armenta2008}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author lists in your sample `bib` entries are wrapped in braces (`{...}`). Moreover author names aren't delimited with `and`. This prevents BibTeX/biber from parsing names correctly. Refer to `biblatex-examples.bib` from the documentation for proper `bib` file format.

```
@ARTICLE{AnderssonS1999,
  author = {Andersson, S.},
  ...
  volume = {30},
  ...
}

@ARTICLE{armenta2008,
  author = {Armenta, J.K. and Dunn, P.O. and Whittingham, L.A.},
  ...
  volume = {125},
  ...
}
```

The `bib` entry should provide only the data. Most formatting, delimiters and punctuation should be handled with biblatex.